# center plot function with tikzpicture

Tags: pgfplots

I've to plot this function: y=-0.002822*x^2 + 1.456*x - 89.314 in the x domain between 75 and 200, and y domain between 0 to 100. 
If I use

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=75,ymin=0]
\addplot[]{-0.002822*(x^2) + 1.456*x - 89.314};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It gives back an empty graph.

Comment: Have you tried `xmin=75,xmax=200,ymin=0,ymax=100,domain=75:200`? (in other words, writing in `pgfplots` what you said in text...).  And please, make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: ok it works, ty.

Comment: The default domain is `-5:5`.

Answer (score 2):

These are the default values for `domain`, y range and x range in pgfplots:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            ]
            \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: showing pgfplots defaults]

If you want different things, just specify them:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=75, xmax=200,
           ymin=0,ymax=100,
           domain=75:200]
        \addplot[]{-0.002822*(x^2) + 1.456*x - 89.314};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Correct image]

Notice that the default for x and y range is to autoscale them, so really you could just say, setting just your `domain`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
           domain=75:200]
        \addplot[]{-0.002822*(x^2) + 1.456*x - 89.314};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and have

[image: autoscaled]